# sjoin 'contains'/'within' seems to be returning a bunch of incorrect rows

Tags: geopandas

I'm trying to figure out which of a bunch of lat/lon points fall within a certain region of the ocean by using a geopandas sjoin.  But what I'm finding is that if I use an sjoin by 'within' or, equivalently, 'contains' - I end up with this weird set of points that are all bounded by the top and bottom latitudes of the region of interest, but have longitudes that that range all over.

Here's the code:

```
pmnm # this is the region of the ocean I'm interested in
geopoints # this is the set of all points
# sjoin to find geopoints that are "within" pmnm
pmnm_points = geopandas.sjoin(geopoints, pmnm, op='within', how='inner')
```

But it's giving me way too many points - the area I'm interested in is in red, and all the points that are supposedly "within" it are in blue:

[image: too many points!]

If I the sjoin using 'intersects' instead, i.e.:
`pmnm_points = geopandas.sjoin(geopoints, pmnm, op='intersects', how='inner')`
then I get only the following 723 points that are actually where they should be:

[image: correct points!]

And now here's the really weird part.  If I take the larger set of points (that seem to all be bounded by the latitudes of the area, but not the actual contour) and basically *manually* check whether they're contained/within, I only get the 723 points that I thought ought to be showing up anyways:

```
num_contained = 0
for i in range(pmnm_points.shape[0]):
    if pmnm.contains(pmnm_points.iloc[i]['geometry']).iloc[0]:
        num_contained += 1
print(num_contained)
# prints 723 -- the correct number! what the heck!
```

So my question is: why are these points that aren't "within" the area still being picked up in the sjoin operation?  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like this may actually be an issue in pygeos. I uninstalled pygeos and the regular geopandas is able to run the sjoin correctly.